# Why am I getting nodata values when using ST_Clip to crop a section out of a strictly larger raster?

Tags: sql, gis, postgis, raster

I am trying to clip/crop out a map tile from a raster but I am getting a line of nodata values/pixels at the top, even though I have confirmed that the polygon I am cropping/clipping to lies is contained within the bounds of the raster I am clipping.

Here is an attempt at a simple reproducible case. Even though the polygon in the second argument to `ST_Clip` lies completely within the polygon of the raster, the result has `0` (`nodata`) values for the top row:

```
WITH tile AS (
SELECT 
    ST_Clip(
        ST_AsRaster(
            ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((174.99958333333333 -40.250416666666666,175.49958333333333 -40.250416666666666,175.49958333333333 -40.750416666666666,174.99958333333333 -40.750416666666666,174.99958333333333 -40.250416666666666))', 4326),
            600,
            600,
            '8BUI', 
            255, 
            0),
        ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((175.078125 -40.71395582628603,175.078125 -40.44694705960049,175.4296875 -40.44694705960049,175.4296875 -40.71395582628603,175.078125 -40.71395582628603))', 4326))
    AS rast)
        
SELECT x, y, val
FROM tile, ST_PixelAsPoints(tile.rast, 1, exclude_nodata_value=>FALSE)
ORDER BY y ASC
```

The result of this will show that all the `y=0` rows have a value of `0` (`nodata`), even though the outer raster is all `255`s. I would have expected the result to be all `255`s since we are clipping a smaller shape out of a larger one that is all `255`s.